# Installing ubuntu dualboot - windows wont start

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, efi

I was installing Ubuntu on one old notebook on the same HDD as windows. There was no EFI partition so I create one during the ubuntu installation process. There were some errors and in the end, I removed EFI and installed ubuntu without EFI. Ubuntu is working well but I can't run windows 8.

In boot options, I have two options [something 0 something, something 1 something].
I tried both but they run only Ubuntu(probably one is not working and automatically skip).

And I just don't know how to run windows when there was no EFI partition. What should I do?

[PARTITIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9SD.jpg)

There is no repair that is working from booted windows usb.

Comment: Reinstall Windows then maybe reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: The same Issue has recently occurred for another User of this Web-Site, @Kvikino. The Problem comes from the fact that, when a Flavor of the _Linux_ Operating System comes on the scene, it manages to mess up the Master Boot Record beyond the reach of the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Operating System. It is definitely possible to revive it using some Command-Line Interventions. However, most people simply first install their _Linux_ Flavor (in your case, your _Ubuntu_ Flavor) and then they come with their _Microsoft_ _Windows_ Flavor and let it do what it wants. _Linux_ is simply smarter.

Comment: Problem is that i cant delete files from win 10 i need to retrieve them.

Comment: If it is Windows 10 in BIOS boot mode, you may have fast start on. You need to temporarily restore a Windows boot loader to MBR, fix Windows & restore grub. You need both Windows repair/install disk with repair console & Ubuntu live installer and either Boot-Repair or know how to mount install & restore grub. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation & https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: boot-repair in ubuntu solved the problem. Thanks for help and time :)